# How can I sanely import EPS images into Visio without losing their features?

Tags: images, microsoft-visio, import, eps, image-formats

I have this (relatively complex I believe) EPS image, which I want to use in an MS Visio 2013 sheet. I've tried:

- **'Insert Picture' directly**: No EPS support.
- **Inkscape -> EMF -> Insert Picture**: Coloring/lighting degraded.
- **Inkscape -> WMF -> Insert Picture**: Coloring/lighting degraded (differently).
- **Inkscape -> SVG -> Insert Picture**: Visio gives a bunch of SVG parsing errors and produces the outlines just right - but with no colors.
- **Print to PDF any which way -> Insert Picture**: No PDF insertion support.

There's only one way which seems to have worked so far:

- **New Word Document -> Insert Picture of the EPS -> Save to file -> Visio Insert Object from file** This displays correctly, but you need to mess with the document page within word; and resizing by Visio sometimes fails (or worse) and you need to go into Word to resize the EPS, etc. That's just sad.

So is there a sane way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have been wondering about this for 2 years and have not figured out how to do all the "insane" ways you suggested (even though I tried).

In case you're still wondering. I've settled for https://cloudconvert.com/eps-to-svg

takes 1 second. might not work 10000% with weird vector images but it gets me from matlab to visio quick

Comment: Link-only software recommendations tend to be viewed as spam.  Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance.  Key point, explain how to accomplish the result instead of just mentioning the name of a tool.

Comment: Noticed the thread was quite old, but Cloud Convert are still up and running and worked well for me. It was very simple, the link supplied above took you to a page that narrowed down your choice to eps upload and svg download. Once uploaded hit the "Start Conversion" button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: My only complaint with CloudConvert was that it did not retain transparencey